# Error: number of observations in y not equal to the number of rows of x

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

Here is my code:

```
ames_train_x <- model.matrix(Value ~ ., train)[, -1]
ames_train_y <- log(train$Value)

ames_test_x <- model.matrix(Value ~ ., test)[, -1]
ames_test_y <- log(test$Value)

# Applying LASSO REGRESSION to data

ames_lasso <- glmnet(
  x = ames_train_x,
  y = ames_train_y,
  alpha = 1
)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in glmnet(x = ames_train_x, y = ames_train_y, alpha = 1) : 
>     number of observations in y (3528) not equal to the number of rows of x (3527)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When doing matrix multiplication AB, number of columns in A should equal number of rows in B. Looks like you are hitting something similar here.

Comment: If you provide your `train` and `test` data, perhaps we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have NA values in train, model.matrix throws out the rows with NA, see example with mtcars below:

```
library(glmnet)
df <- mtcars
train_x <- model.matrix(mpg ~ ., df)[, -1]
dim(train_x)
1] 32 10
train_y <- log(df$mpg)
fit = glmnet(y=train_y,x=train_x)

# now we set 1 value to be NA
df["Fiat 128","cyl"]<-NA
train_x <- model.matrix(mpg ~ ., df)[, -1]
Fiat 128" %in% rownames(train_x)
[1] FALSE
dim(train_x)
1] 31 10
```

And fitting this, gives you the error you see:

```
fit = glmnet(y=train_y,x=train_x)
Error in glmnet(y = train_y, x = train_x) : 
  number of observations in y (32) not equal to the number of rows of x (31)
```